# Static option is disabled while creating a new Java class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, static

When I try to create a new Java class in Eclipse, under the "Modifiers" section `static` option is shown as disabled. Why is that?

Comment: A Top level class cannot be *static*., thats why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `static` modifier means a member (be it a field, a method or an inner class) belongs to the **class** instead of to a specific **instance** of it. A top level class does not belong to anything (it is not within another class), and thus cannot be `static`. Only an inner class can be `static`.

Comment: @Saik0 - Another point to be noted is : *a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.* check [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Answer (score 1):

Top level class can be **public** or **default** (package specific). inner class can be **public**, **default** ,**protected** , **private**, **static**.

Answer (score 0):

Only inner classes can be static.

```
public class Foo {
    public static class Bar {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to be an Inner Class that you can make static, not the Top level one That's why.